# How to properly resize an image?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, convolution

I am a starter for the CNN DL. 
During CNN code I faced this error:

> Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 3 from 1 for
>   'conv2d_3/convolution' (op: 'Conv2D') with input shapes: [?,19,1,64],
>   [3,3,64,64]

My image data show `300(w)`, `855(h)` pixels size.

For the np array transformation, I applied below.

```
(width,height = 28)->>
img = cv2.resize(img, None, fx = img_width/img.shape[0], fy = img_height/img.shape[1])
                x.append(img/256)
                y.append(label)
```

And then, I tried CNN by using this:

```
model.add(Convolution2D(16,(3,3), border_mode='same', activation='relu', input_shape=x_train.shape[1:]))

x_train.shape[1:] = (80,10,3)
```

Please help to fix this error.
Thank you for read.

Comment: Also, I added to more layers.

Comment: Two more below layer.

Comment: model.add(Convolution2D(64,(3,3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

Answer (score 0):

you have an input with the shape (19x1x64) where 64 is the number of channels. That's why your 3x3 convolution operation cannot be performed. What probably is happening:
**- you are resizing your image in a wrong way (hence the 19x1x64 dimension as opposed to the 28x28x3 you potentially intended to achieve).**
How to solve this? check out your resizing again and print your image shape after resize, see if this is what you aimed for.

Comment: #TheEngineer Thank you for the ans. As follow your ans, I think that ma major problem is resize. Before the consideration of it, I have one more Q. At first, i gave input_shape (80,10,3). It means 80,10 size and 3 channels. But you commented 64 in error sentence is # of channels. Can you answer the details of it? Thank you for reading.

Comment: #TheEngineer Also, I don't know how  (19x1x64) happened at the error sentence. If it is possible, please give ans. Thank you.

Comment: Let's try something. Comment out your code for anything else beside the resizing. Try to load your image, resize and print it's shape. That would be a good first step to see what kind of image shape we are getting after the resize.

Comment: Finally, I solved this problem. The resized value depend on the size of original image data. So I had to consider the size of original data before decision of resized value. Thank you for your help. Have a nice day!

Comment: I am glad it worked out. FYI, if the answer provided was helpful, please accept it as correct answer so that the question is marked as closed.